# Mysql create table based on another table including indexes

Tags: sql, mysql, database, performance

I need to create a table based on another table in MYsql including the constraints and indices.

I have following scenario:

Table A- exists probably with millions of rows.
I want to create table B with exactly same as table A (including constraints and indices).
Process data from A and some other source and insert to B.
At the end of processing drop table A(drop indices associated with table A) and Rename table B to A including indices.

What is the best way to do this? Performance is my real concern.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In cases like this, we assume you know the structure of the table. In other words, you are not asking "how do I find out what all of these columns, indexes and constraints are".

Second we tend to assume that all data in table A is valid, so you do not need to enforce constraints while copying from A to B.

Your "some other source" is a wildcard.  I'm assuming you do not know if this other source contains valid data, and would suggest:

1) Create B w/o indeces or constraints

2) Copy/bulk insert from "other source" to B

3) Execute constraints by issuing SELECTS to find invalid rows.  Skip this step if you know the data is valid.  Once it is ok to proceed:

4) Copy A to B in "chunks".  The issue here is that a straight SELECT...INTO... of all X millions of rows will take forever (because of explosion of resources required to do it in a single implied transaction), but a row-by-row will also take forever (because its just plain slow to do one row at a time).  So you process chunks of 1000 or 10000 rows at a time.

5) When all data is copied over, add the indeces

6) Add the constraints

7) Drop A

8) Rename B

Comment: `CREATE TABLE ... LIKE oldtable` could come in handy here, though it will copy over index definitions.

Comment: Thanks Marc, I probably use LIKE, my hesitation is because of the following description about the LIKE.. statement. CREATE TABLE ... LIKE does not preserve any DATA DIRECTORY or INDEX DIRECTORY table options that were specified for the original table, or any foreign key definitions. Currently I don't have any foreign key in the table, so I probably go with this. @Ken, I can not do as you suggested as I need to process content of the original table with new data simultaneously.